# How to break out of the for loop in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Well the problem is simple, I am using a query within the for loop and and I want to get out of the for loop if I get the count less than 15, otherwise increase the assigned. But I can't be able to use the break statement and the loop will continue to execute even after the first callback.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < test; i++) {

                var sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM `tb_members` WHERE `assigned`=?";
                connection.query(sql, [assigned], function (err, response) {

                    if (response[0].count < 15) {

                        callback(assigned);

                    }
                    else {
                        ++assigned;

                        if (i == test - 1) {
                            callback(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way your code is written, all your SQL queries are going to get started at once.  Then, sometime later, the queries will start returning with results.  So, you can't break out of the `for` loop because it's already done and all SQL queries have already been sent.

If you want to decide whether to send the next query based on the previous one's results, then you have to only send one at a time and because of the async nature of the results, you can't use a `for` loop for that.

One way of sending the queries one at a time and then deciding whether to send the next one is this:

```
function sendQueries() {
    var i = 0;

    function next() {
        if (i < test) {
            var sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM `tb_members` WHERE `assigned`=?";
            connection.query(sql, [assigned], function (err, response) {
                i++;
                if (response[0].count < 15) {
                    callback(assigned);
                } else {
                    ++assigned;
                    if (i == test - 1) {
                        callback(0);
                    }
                }
                // here you can decide whether you want to do the next iteration
                // or not by either calling next() or not.
                next();
            });
        }
    }
    next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using async to write such a loop. If you want a serial behavior - you might consider using async.eachSeries, and then you can stop the loop by calling the callback function with error. At that point the loop will not execute anymore. But in the error handler - ignore the err.

Check it out here: https://github.com/caolan/async#collections