# AJAX - Wait for data to append before looping next

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I am creating a drop down list in JavaScript, I am loading the data via Ajax and JSON, at the moment my code loops through a set of departments and runs into the ajax call in each iteration.

My problem is that my data seems to be appending in a random order, its likely that its loading in the order of whichever loads quickest.

I want to be able to loop through my Ajax call and append the data in the order that I declare (for each department).
is this something that can be done?

Here is my code:

```
//-- Ajax --
var departments = ['Accounts', 'Commercial', 'Installation', 'Production', 'Sales'];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < departments.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/EmployeesDropDown",
        data: '{X: "' + departments[i] + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text json",
        async: true,
        success: createdropdown,
        failure: function () {
            alert("FAIL!");
        }
    });
}


//-- Creates dropdown --
function createdropdown(data) {
...appends all the data to my drop down list...
  }
```

Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you in advance.

***EDIT: This question is different from the related ones because I need to be able to loop through the string array, rather than just iterating based on numbers.***

Comment: use javascript promises

Comment: or just do a single ajax call

Comment: Seems a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978843/how-to-make-for-loop-wait-until-async-call-was-successful-before-to-continue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the departments in the order they appear in the `departments` array you could load them one by one, waiting for each ajax request to finish until you start the next request.

Here is an example:

```js
var departments = ['Accounts', 'Commercial', 'Installation', 'Production', 'Sales'];
var i = 0;

function reqDep(department) {

  /*
  Since i can't use ajax here let's use a promise.
  */

  var p = new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      res(department)
    }, 1000)
  })
  return p;

  // This is what you would actually do.

  /*
  var data =  '{X: "' + department + '"}'
  return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/EmployeesDropDown",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text json",
  });
  */  
}

function initDepartments(index) {
  reqDep(departments[index])
  // Here you would use `.done(function(data...`
  // I am using `.then(function(data...`
  // because of the promise.
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    if(i < departments.length) {
      initDepartments(i)
    }
  })
  i++;
};

initDepartments(i)
```