# Can a JS/Jquery waiting animation be applied or have the appearance of covering a table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, animation

How to attach a waiting animation to a row?

I want to create a table that will enable AJAX to wait for a response ( *I'm struggling with Ebay timing out in the browser and Aysnc or multi-treading is beyond my capabilities*).. I found a nice [ASYNC solution here using a counter to wait for each response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22979011/2154032).

Then I found [a nice waiting animation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964871/2154032), although it seems older and a lot comments mention that there are problems with it in newer AJAX scenarios.

I feel a better looking UI would be to have the animation directly over the row in waiting for the response. ( *or maybe I simply move the row in waiting to a new table above called completed" ..hmmm*)

Would you use coordinates and a div? or clear the table columns for a div? Lots of concepts, no success yet.. thoughts?

Concept:
[image]

Comment: Could you hide the table and display a loader for a set amount of time then show the table again?

Comment: it a good idea, ..I think I want the user to have access to the table between uploads (15-45 secs) ..maybe just to look things over or even uncheck a row if needed. I think the more I think about it, either moving them up to a new "completed rows" table or just create a column just for "status" Add/waiting/completed  ..  thanks for your suggestion! Tough choices.